# How to make a function ignore an argument

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, options

### Motivation

I am trying to call a function `f`, that has either 1 or 2 (or multiple) parameters, from a function `g` that uses optional arguments

```
Clear[f, g]

f[x_] := "foo"
f[x_, y_] := {x, y}


Options[g] = {"y" -> 5};
g[m_, OptionsPattern[]] := f[3*m, OptionValue["y"]]


g[2] (* {6,5} *)
g[2, "y" -> -6] (* {6,-6}*)
```

**I want be able call `f` with 1 parameter from `g` to get**

```
g[2, "y"->someMagicMethod] = "foo"
```

I have tried

```
g[2, "y" -> Blank[]] (* {6,_} *)
g[2, "y" -> Nothing] (* {6} *)
g[2, "y" -> None] (* {6,None} *)
g[2, "y" -> Null] (* {6,Null} *)
g[2, "y" -> Identity] (* {6,Identity} *)
```

### Possible Solution

An idea is to place the arguments into a list and take advantage of the fact that `Nothing` disappears when in a list and then using `Apply`

```
Options[g2] = {"y" -> 5};
g2[m_, OptionsPattern[]] := f@@{3*m, OptionValue["y"]}; (* arguments in a list *)


g2[6, "y" -> Nothing] (* "foo" *)
```

I'm not sure that this is the best method as you need to ensure that the list is ordered correctly before applying `f`.

Is there a more general solution that scales well with `f` or `g` increasing in complexity of arguments / optional values?

Am I missing a better "Option" way to set up `g` using `FilterRules` etc. or patterns ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Not sure if this helps but the actual case I am working on is where `f` is an inbuilt function, `FindClusters`. I have a function `g` that calls `FindClusters[data,n]` but sometimes wants to call it with `FindClusters[data]`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think that is the issue I am trying to solve? i.e How to get `g` to pick between the two versions of `f`. PS :I fixed a typo, not sure if that helps?

Comment: Just checking, are you confusing optional arguments (see `Optional`, denoted by e.g. `x_:default` or `x : patt : default`) with `Options`? you're calling options "optional arguments" and wanted to make sure this was simply casual usage rather than an indication you were conflating them :)

Comment: Also, with your function as-is, I believe you're looking for `"y" -> Sequence[]` :) A more robust version though might ask for a special token, e.g. `Automatic`, and then check the option value (e.g. `If[OptionValue["y"] === Automatic, f[x], f[x, OptionValue["y"]]`)

Comment: @thorimur thanks for your feedback the functions I am looking at in real life both use `Optional` and have default arguments, I don't think I have conflated the two., ie optional arguments refers to `Options`.

Your comment on Sequence looks like it might the right thing I am looking for? Would it be possible to submit an answer please?

Comment: ok, i suppose that's just a language usage thing then! in my experience "optional arguments" refers to *ordinary* arguments which may be optionally supplied or not. in contrast, options are often thought of as a different sort of argument (given the wolfram language's special handling of them), and are simply called "options". (and confusingly, i don't hear the adjective "optional" ever used to mean "pertaining to options")